# How to show prefilled data in the right table of the React Dual Listbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listbox

I have implemented the React Dual Listbox library in my project. I have a update employee detail form where in the Listbox right hand side table, I need to show the items the user had selected previously while submitting basic detail form.

Now whenever I open the update form, I call an api which gives me the data (in my case a list of items) which user has selected previously while submitting the form. I use this data to prefill the react dual listbox right hand side table which shows the selected items. But, I am not able to prefill it.
I used the selected attribute of the <DualListBox> tag by storing the array of items from the api into the selected array, but still was not able to show the prefilled data.

Please refer [React Dual Listbox](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-dual-listbox)

How can I show the prefilled data?

Comment: Your question has no code. I think the question would make more sense to others.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this or used alternate package? i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a little bit late for this but in case somebody else has the same problem :

You need to pass only the values in the selected array .

```
    options: [
                { value: 'io', label: 'Io' },
                { value: 'europa', label: 'Europa' },
                { value: 'ganymede', label: 'Ganymede' },
                { value: 'callisto', label: 'Callisto' },
            ]

    selected: ['io', 'europa']
```

Io and Europa options will appear in the right listbox as selected .